# Deriving Stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am having a difficulty in deriving stochastic differential equations from geometric Brownian motion dynamics.

Assume S follows the geometric Brownian motion dynamics, dS = μSdt + σSdZ, with μ and σ constants.
Derive the stochastic differential equation satisfied by
y = 2S, y = S^2, y=e^S

Doing any of these examples will help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want us to do you homework, here I will explain you how to do it.

The key is to do Ito's formula:
If $ f \in \mathcal{C}^2$ then 
$$f(S_t) = f(S_0) + \int_0^t f'(S_t)dS_t + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(S_t) d[S]_t$$

And so considering the differential form:
$$ df(S_t) = f'(S_t)dS_t + \frac{1}{2} f''(S_t) d[S]_t $$

Where of course $[S]_t$ denotes the quadratic variation of S. 
In your case: $[S]_t= \int_0^t (\sigma S_t)^2 dt $ assuming $Z_t$ is a BM.

You can apply this formula to $f(x)=2x, f(x)=x^2, f(x)=e^x,.. $

Can you finish the exercise?